# Print model summary in R markdown without running model

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have run a logistic mixed model that took about 3 hours to fit. I saved the model as an object in my global environment, and I want to include the model summary in my R markdown document. However, I don't want knitr to run the model when putting the html together (that would take 3 more hours to run). I just want to print the summary of the model I've already run.

Knitr throws an error saying that the model object isn't in its scope.

How do I get knitr to access the model object I've already created and not re-run the model when compiling the document?

Comment: suppose one approach is you could save the model object, and then read it in within your rmd file (see saveRDS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would save the model as an RDS object, and then load it in the RMarkdown document. You can then load the RDS object, while hiding this fact if you want to simply present the code that you ran. For example, see the code below which would fit and save/reload a linear model:

```
fit <- lm(x ~ y)
saveRDS(fit, "fit.RDS")
```

Then, in the RMarkdown document

````
## (if you do not wish to hide the fact that you are loading it, then omit `echo = FALSE`)
```{r, echo = FALSE}
fit <- readRDS("fit.RDS")
## To show the code that fit the model. 
## `eval = FALSE` means the code is not run while knitting.
```{r, eval = FALSE}
fit <- lm(x ~ y)
```
````

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it has solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do should be to check your workspace with ls(). If the model is not there, you will need to rerun it. If you do see it, you can just print the summary in the console. When you try to knit your document it will want to run the entire rmd

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is to avoid running the whole rmd and having to re-run the model (which takes 3 hours to fit). The model is in the workspace. I just want to print the summary.  But using summary(model) in the rmd does not work, because knitr can't see the model in the global environment.

Comment: Have you tried just running summary(model) in the console? The problem with using an rmd with a long runtime is that you can't just knit one section of it, because each time you knit it has no memory of the objects created the last time you knitted. I recommend either using the console or just a simply .R script if there is no way to decrease the runtime

Comment: Yes.  It works in the console because the model is stored in the global environment. How do I get knitr to see that object, instead of trying to create a new one?  The goal here is to share the model summary with my collaborators via the rmd output.  Not just myself.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Knitr works in a self contained environment, and cannot access the global environment. If it could access the global environment, the rmd would not be reproducible. However, one possible solution (untested) may be to save your model into an .RData file, and load that in with your rmd.

Comment: The other answers fixed my problem.  Save the object to my drive using saveRDS, then load the object in the rmd file.